# How to convert SQL in mysql binlog to html?

Tags: sql, mysql-real-escape-string

My site was hacked and I was able to retrieve some SQL from binlog, they look like

```
<p>some text</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"images/2019-04-27/1.jpg\" alt=\"1\" /></p>
```

I need to convert `\r\n` to new line and unescape the double quotes. 
Of course I can write my own function to achieve this, but since there are lots of SQLs to convert, I am not sure if `\r\n` and `\"` are the only things I need to deal with.

I think the key here is to find out what this conversion is called so I can google. I tried "html encode", "html escape"  and "sql escape", none of them worked.

So, is there any PHP or JAVASCRIPT function that can handle this? Or is there any online tools?

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically converts /n into a new line for you. For example, if you go onto this website here - www.repl.it/languages/python3

`string = '<p>some text</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"images/2019-04-27/1.jpg\" alt=\"1\" /></p>'`

`print(string)`

Copy the above code into it and you'll see the string is given a new line

If you need to use a multi line string put the string in 3 quotation marks like so.

```
string = '''
I
am
a 
multi
line
string
'''
```